# Python remove a character with lambda

Tags: python, lambda

I want to remove “X” form this string.
What is wrong with my code?

```
garbled = "IXXX aXXmX aXXXnXoXXXXXtXhXeXXXXrX sXXXXeXcXXXrXeXt mXXeXsXXXsXaXXXXXXgXeX!XX"
message=filter(lambda x: x=="X" x=='' ,garbled)
print message
```

I know that this one works:

```
garbled = "IXXX aXXmX aXXXnXoXXXXXtXhXeXXXXrX sXXXXeXcXXXrXeXt mXXeXsXXXsXaXXXXXXgXeX!XX"
message=filter(lambda x: x!="X" ,garbled)
print message
```

Comment: What are you expecting `x=="X" x==''` to do?

Comment: filter() is not a replace operation. Are you looking for `message = garbled.replace("X", "")`?

Comment: Dear @ThomasWeller , I am new and learning here. I just want to understand why (@yatu) ```x=="X" x==''``` is not deleting the X character

Comment: to replace characters just use: `garbled.replace("X","")`

Comment: @ipj  Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the mistake in lambda-condition. You even do not need `string.replace()`. Lambda-condition must have this syntax:

**Use the syntax lambda input: true_return if condition else false_return to return true_return if condition is True and false_return otherwise. condition can be an expression involving input.**([There are more examples](https://kite.com/python/answers/how-to-use-an-if-statement-in-a-lambda-function-in-python))

```
garbled = "IXXX aXXmX aXXXnXoXXXXXtXhXeXXXXrX sXXXXeXcXXXrXeXt mXXeXsXXXsXaXXXXXXgXeX!XX"
f = lambda x: "" if x in "X" else x
message = filter(f, garbled)
"".join(message)
```

Answer (score 0):

[`filter()`](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/functions.html) is a built-in function of Python. The documentation says:

> `filter(function, iterable)`

So you need two things to call the filter function: another function and basically a list of things.

For `iterable`, a string is fine, because a string is a list of characters. That means, Python can perform a loop on it. That's what's important for an iterable.

For `function`, let's read on:

> Construct an iterator from those elements of iterable for which function returns true. iterable may be either a sequence, a container which supports iteration, or an iterator. If function is None, the identity function is assumed, that is, all elements of iterable that are false are removed.

So it says you need a function that returns `True` for those items that shall be iterated. For all items you don't want, return `False`.

Such a function could be:

```
def remove_all_X(s):
    if s == "X":
        return False  # because you want to remove all "X"
    return True  # all other characters
```

This can be inversed to

```
def remove_all_X(s):
    if s != "X":
        return True  # non-"X"
    return False  # "X"
```

And then shortened to

```
def remove_all_X(s):
    return s != "X"
```

You can then use it like

```
garbled = "IXXX aXXmX aXXXnXoXXXXXtXhXeXXXXrX sXXXXeXcXXXrXeXt mXXeXsXXXsXaXXXXXXgXeX!XX"
message=filter(remove_all_X ,garbled)
print message
```

Note that there are no braces after `remove_all_X`, because you don't want to pass the result of the function, but the function itself. Remember: `filter()` needs a function.

A function that is as simple as

```
def remove_all_X(s):
    return s != "X"
```

is often expressed as a lambda. You remove the definition (`def`) and write `lambda` + the parameter instead. The `return` keyword is also omitted. And you get:

```
labmda s: s != "X"
```

Now you use that instead of the function name:

```
message=filter(labmda s: s != "X" ,garbled)
```

> What is wrong with my code?

Let's try moving backwards in the explanation, but starting from your code

```
lambda x: x=="X" x==''
```

Adding all the stuff that was removed:

```
def remove_all_X(x):
    return x=="X" x==''
```

Do you see that this does not result in a valid `return` statement? It looks like you want to return 2 things (maybe a tuple `(x=="X", x=='')`) or a combination of two things (maybe `x=="X" or x==""`)?

The compiler cannot interpret your wish and doesn't understand what to do.

Answer (score -1):

It's because lambda and filter just don't work like that.
This is what happens when you try the first one

```
>>> message=filter(lambda x: x=="X" x=='', garbled)
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The second one basically allows every letter where `letter!='X'` (so where every letter is *not* 'X')

The Syntax Error appears because filter doesn't find every instance of a letter and replace it. It simply looks for a letter and excludes them, so putting the  `x==''` after the `x=="X"` doesn't make sense because there is an unexpected space, so `Syntax Error`...

Comment: THANKS so much this is exactly what I was looking for  

Comment: There's no unexpected space. You can add as many spaces there as you like.